# pandas custom idxmax() function with special handling of equality

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a csv file full of electoral data. My raw sample could be represented as:

```
        city      party1     party2     party3
   0    city1     50         107        114
   1    city2     181        323        326
   2    city3     26         28         75
   3    city4     32         47         59
   4    ciy5      8          21         21
```

I used the idxmax() function of pandas to create a new column, called "winner", like this :

```
 mydf['winner'] = mydf[['party1','party2','party3']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

My goal was to determine which party was in first position in each city. Here the result:

```
        city      party1     party2     party3      winner
   0    city1     50         107        114         party3
   1    city2     181        323        326         party3
   2    city3     26         28         75          party3
   3    city4     32         47         59          party3
   4    ciy5      8          21         21          party2
```

The winner's value of the last raw is false, because party2 and party3 have the same score.

Is it possible to include one exception with the function idxmax considers equality of two values and gives 'Equality'?

Comment: So what should be the value in the winner column? A concatenation of the strings party2 and party3?

Comment: Personaly, something like 'equality' should be the best!

Comment: You need to be more explicit what you want to get. You're asking for a custom `idxmax` which knows how many levels it is looking at (and that might vary across columns). And then generates a context-sensitive label. To quibble, this is 'Equality' only between party2, party3 but not party1. (I'd call that 'Tie' but not 'Equality')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for compare `subset` with [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) values per row, then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) them and where is value higher as `1` there are duplicates max. So then can be overwrite value of `idxmax` by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with mask `s > 1`:

```
a = mydf[['party1','party2','party3']]
mydf['winner'] = a.idxmax(axis=1)

s = a.eq(a.max(axis=1), axis=0).sum(axis=1)
print (s)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64

mydf['winner'] = mydf['winner'].mask(s > 1, 'Equality')
print (mydf)
    city  party1  party2  party3    winner
0  city1      50     107     114    party3
1  city2     181     323     326    party3
2  city3      26      28      75    party3
3  city4      32      47      59    party3
4   ciy5       8      21      21  Equality
```

If need also values multiple `df` by values of columns by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html), then `apply` `join` and last remove `,` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
a = mydf[['party1','party2','party3']]
df = a.eq(a.max(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
  party1 party2 party3
0  False  False   True
1  False  False   True
2  False  False   True
3  False  False   True
4  False   True   True

mydf['winner'] = df.mul(df.columns.to_series())
                   .apply(','.join, axis=1)
                   .str.strip(',')
print (mydf)
    city  party1  party2  party3         winner
0  city1      50     107     114         party3
1  city2     181     323     326         party3
2  city3      26      28      75         party3
3  city4      32      47      59         party3
4   ciy5       8      21      21  party2,party3
```

Comment: Hello jezrael, I tried the first solution following every step very carefuly, but then I've got this error : TypeError: mask() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given  :-/...

Comment: What is your version of pandas?

Comment: Got the 0.14.1 (my laptob runs on Debian). Too old for use mask function ?

Comment: I think there is problem. Last version is `0.19.0`

Comment: Ok I'm going to check how update my stuff... Many thanks to you !

Comment: One last little thing. I installed 0.19.0 version, the mask worked very well, but when I used to_csv() function in my df, the result was blank cells instead of "Equality". I probably missed something again !