# Get List of Column Names that are the (joint) highest, across a subset of the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame from which I would like to get a list of all column names that are the joint highest across a subset of the data. I have tried the answer from the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331738/pandas-custom-idxmax-function-with-special-handling-of-equality) but I am getting an error. I think it is associated with the "winner" column that is added.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'selection': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'book_1': [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0],
        'book_2': [4.0, 5.2, 6.2, 7.3],
        'book_3': [3.9, 5.2, 6.4, 6.8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['selection', 'book_1', 'book_2', 'book_3'])
data_fields = ['book_1', 'book_2', 'book_3']
a = df[data_fields]
dftmp = a.eq(a.max(axis=1), axis=0)
print(dftmp)
df['winner'] = dftmp.mul(dftmp.columns.to_series()).apply(','.join, axis=1).str.strip(',')

print(df)
```

This gives me the output that I expect in terms of the table, and showing "True" for the columns that have the (joint) highest value from the data, but now how can I get a list of those columns into their own column in my original dataframe?

Apologies if this isn't clear or further information is required, I'll be happy to go into more detail/explain more if needed. Thanks!

```
   book_1  book_2  book_3
0    True    True   False
1   False    True    True
2   False   False    True
3   False    True   False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 149, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 208, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 70, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U6'), dtype('<U6')) -> dtype('<U6')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    df['winner'] = dftmp.mul(dftmp.columns.to_series()).apply(','.join, axis=1).str.strip(',')
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 776, in f
    self, other, pass_op, fill_value=fill_value, axis=axis, level=level
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 620, in _combine_series_frame
    new_data = dispatch_to_series(left, right, func, axis="columns")
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 419, in dispatch_to_series
    new_data = expressions.evaluate(column_op, str_rep, left, right)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 208, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py", line 70, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 407, in column_op
    return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(a.columns))}
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 407, in <dictcomp>
    return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(a.columns))}
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 503, in wrapper
    result = arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 197, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 151, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
  File "/home/oddschecker-juice-finder/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 112, in masked_arith_op
    result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U6'), dtype('<U6')) -> dtype('<U6')
```

Desired output...

```
    book_1  book_2 book_3 winner
0   True    True   False  book_1, book_2
1   False    True    True book_2, book_3
2   False   False    True book_3
3   False    True   False book_2
```

Comment: Please read on [how to make a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's quite hard to help you as of now. As a tip, start by providing sample data in text format and your desired output

Comment: @JuanC Thanks, please see the edit for a simple code example.

Comment: What would your desired output on the example data be?

Comment: There would be an additional column that would contain the string names of the columns that are true, so 0 would be “book_1, book_2” for example.

Comment: Have edited desired output into the original question now, sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: I think I understood your problem. If the question gets reopened I can help you with the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
dftmp['winner'] = dftmp.dot(dftmp.columns+', ').str.strip(', ')
dftmp
```

Output:

```
   book_1  book_2  book_3          winner
0    True    True   False  book_1, book_2
1   False    True    True  book_2, book_3
2   False   False    True          book_3
3   False    True   False          book_2
```